# TypeORM use `.returning` with all visible fields

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

In my query, all fields are being returned because I'm using `.returned("*")`, even those that are marked with `@Exclude`. Is there a way I can apply `.returned("*")` but return only visible fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Nest.js and the problem for me was that I didn't include `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` in my controller. This got rid of all excluded fields.